# how to create a unique bigint primary key in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have a table in cassandra for saving messages. I have uuid as primary key, but I need to send clients bigints as message keys which must be unique for that user.
how can I achieve that? Is there a way to combine user primary key which is bigint and message key to generate a bigint message_id for that user?
or should I use bigint as primary key for messages? if so then how can I generate unique bigints?

Comment: Will you please provide the database design or tables, this will help lot to give you clear answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra allows you to have a compound primary key, in this case, the message_id seems a good candidate to be used as a clustering key.

For more information, you can take a look [here](http://www.sudotutorials.com/tutorials/cassandra/cassandra-primary-key-cluster-key-partition-key.html) and [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompoundPrimaryKeyConcept.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generate auto incremented bigint number in Cassandra.

You have that key generation logic some ware else  and use that as part of index in Cassandra

or

Build your own id service where you fetch your next id. This service will only be run in a single **instance and will be a non scaling scary factor.**